# How can I take a screenshot of only the visible elements of a page in Nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js, webpage-screenshot

I can successfully capture an entire webpage using Nightwatch.js, using the following code snippet:

```
module.exports = {
    'open the page': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('http://localhost')
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .resizeWindow(320, 480)
            .saveScreenshot('./screenshot/mobile/login.png');
    }
}
```

In my scenario, the page I'm opening contains a lot of content which would scroll off the bottom of the page. My captures with the code above are coming out at 320x1200 pixels, and I want them to just come out at 320x480 pixels.

I want to capture only the 'above the fold' elements of the screen, and not the entire webpage, which seems to be the default.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: screenshot of entire page is *default*, is that what you mean?

Comment: Much question, so ambiguity, wow (this will not make any sense if you change your avatar at some point). Maybe you could clarify that you want your screenshot to have the exact dimensions your browser window has. If that is the case, which I assumed in the answer below. Because "visible elements" has a specific CSS meaning.

Comment: To clarify, my captures with the default settings (the code above) are coming out at 320x1200 pixels, and I want them to just come out at 320x480 pixels. I don't really mean 'visible elements', I mean 'above the fold' elements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Consider cropping the saved screenshot, though, unless someone more knowledgeable provides a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requiring a functionality like the one you describe (but using Python, Selenium, and PhantomJS), I ended up saving the screenshot as is and then cropping the saved image using a separate tool (some ImageMagick wrapper). In your case, `png-crop` could be the solution (https://www.npmjs.com/package/png-crop). When, for instance, you specify a window of 320px width and 480px height, the saved screenshot could very well have a width of 320px and a height of 2500px, depending on how "tall" the page is. You could then proceed to crop the saved image to an image of 320px width and 480px height, keeping the upper part of the image.